# Python: not every web page have a certain element

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

When I tried to use urls to scrape web pages, I found that some elements only exists in some pages and other have not. Let's take the code for example

Code:

```
for urls in article_url_set:
    re=requests.get(urls)
    soup=BeautifulSoup(re.text.encode('utf-8'), "html.parser")
    title_tag = soup.select_one('.page_article_title')
    if title_tag=True:
        print(title_tag.text)
    else:
        #do something
```

## if title_tag exits, I want to print them, if it's not, just skip them.

Another thing is that, I need to save other elements and title.tag.text in data.

```
   data={
        "Title":title_tag.text,
        "Registration":fruit_tag.text,
        "Keywords":list2
    }
```

It will have an error cause not all the article have Title, what should I do to skip them when I try to save? **'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'**

Edit: I decide not to skip them and keep them as Null or None.

Answer (score 1):

U code is wrong:

```
for urls in article_url_set:
    re=requests.get(urls)
    soup=BeautifulSoup(re.text.encode('utf-8'), "html.parser")
    title_tag = soup.select_one('.page_article_title')
    if title_tag=True:  # wrong
        print(title_tag.text) 
    else:
        #do something
```

your code if title_tag=True,

changed code title_tag == True

It is recommended to create conditional statements as follows.

`title_tag == True` => `True == title_tag`

This is a way to make an error when making a mistake.

If Code is `True = title_tag`, occur error.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use a truth test to check if the tag is existing, otherwise assign a value like `None`, then you can insert it in the data container :

```
title_tag = soup.select_one('.page_article_title')
if title_tag:
    print(title_tag.text)
    title = title_tag.text
else:
    title = None
```

Or in one line :

```
title = title_tag.text if title_tag else None
```

Comment: Oh thank you! I I actually sorted out yesterday. Do really appreciate all your help!